Quantiles of a series with polars as dataframe
Say I have a dataframe in polars with a column outcome that is some float.
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌─────┬──────────┐
│ a   ┆ outcome  │
│ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪══════════╡
│ 2   ┆ 0.17745  │
│ 2   ┆ 0.712477 │
│ 2   ┆ 0.038308 │
│ 1   ┆ 0.886266 │
│ 2   ┆ 0.578249 │
│ 1   ┆ 0.80318  │
└─────┴──────────┘
""")

How can I get the quantiles of that outcome as a dataframe, i.e. I would like to get something like:
| quantile | value        |
|----------|--------------|
| 0.1      | <some value> |
| 0.2      | <some value> |
| 0.3      | <some value> |
| ...      |              |
| ...      |              |

Notice I would be most interested in a solution without a group by (i.e. across the whole dataframe) but also with a group by where the group is identified by some additional variable, in the example below a would also be of interest.

Do you mind to put an example of input and output data?

For a straightforward practical solution: use numpy.quantile.

You are "[...] interested in a solution without a group by but wit [sic] group by [...]"?

hey - thanks i made a clarification. i would be interested in having this by group (as you already provided) but also across the whole column (i.e. without grouping)

@clog14 Please also add sample output to your question. It is not really clear how you in what format you'd like both the not grouped & grouped quantiles.

We can use a generator expression to generate a polars aggregation for each of quantile of interest. Next, pl.DataFrame.unpivot can be used to obtain the long format specified in the question.
QUANTILES = [0.05, 0.5, 0.95]

(
    df
    .group_by("a")
    .agg(
        pl.col("outcome").quantile(q).alias(str(q))
        for q in QUANTILES
    )
    .unpivot(index="a", variable_name="quantile")
    .with_columns(pl.col("quantile").cast(pl.Float64))
)

shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ a   ┆ quantile ┆ value    │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 2   ┆ 0.05     ┆ 0.093151 │
│ 1   ┆ 0.05     ┆ 0.2693   │
│ 2   ┆ 0.5      ┆ 0.90896  │
│ 1   ┆ 0.5      ┆ 0.356496 │
│ 2   ┆ 0.95     ┆ 0.982695 │
│ 1   ┆ 0.95     ┆ 0.356496 │
└─────┴──────────┴──────────┘


hey - thanks! this is not the output i look for. the quantiles should be in the rows. pls see my original post.

@clog14 Thanks for the sample output - I've edited my answer.

Hey thanks - this would also be the way in which I thought. The conversion to string and from string seems somewhat ugly. but i guess there is no other way then?

@clog14 Please include all relevant information in your question! It sounds like you already have a solution, which you want improved, but this is not mentioned in the question..

Another way to do it without unpivot is concat_list and explode
The non-grouped version looks like
(
    df
    .select(
        quantile = pl.concat_list(pl.lit(q/100) for q in range(0,110,10)), 
        value = pl.concat_list(pl.col('outcome').quantile(q/100) for q in range(0,110,10))
        )
    .explode('quantile','value')
    )

and then grouped is just
(
    df
    .group_by('a')
    .agg(
        quantile = pl.concat_list(pl.lit(q/100) for q in range(0,110,10)), 
        value = pl.concat_list(pl.col('outcome').quantile(q/100) for q in range(0,110,10))
        )
    .explode('quantile','value')
    )

